# nodejs-0.4.2 segfault on start (Fixed in v 0.4.5)

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault

**Greetings, to save your time this bug was fixed in v0.4.5** 
I ran into a rather weird problem while installing node.js today and sifted through the mail archives but couldn't quite pin it!. so I posted the problem to nodejs [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/20170)

just a heads up that I changed `snapshot='snapshot=on'` from wscript in
Node to `snapshot=''`.
I did this because prior to doing this I encountered the following
error during make:

`scons: *** [obj/release/snapshot.cc] Error -11`

Now to the steps I followed.

*logged in as root

---Start of configure

```
adil-X:/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2 # ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nodejs    
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++    
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp    
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar    
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib    
Checking for g++                         : ok    
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc    
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar    
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib    
Checking for gcc                         : ok    
Checking for library dl                  : yes    
Checking for openssl                     : yes    
Checking for library util                : yes    
Checking for library rt                  : yes    
--- libeio ---    
Checking for library pthread             : yes    
Checking for function pthread_create     : yes    
Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes    
Checking for futimes(2)                  : yes    
Checking for readahead(2)                : yes    
Checking for fdatasync(2)                : yes    
Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes    
Checking for sendfile(2)                 : yes    
Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : yes    
--- libev ---    
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : yes
Checking for function inotify_init       : yes    
Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : yes    
Checking for function epoll_ctl          : yes    
Checking for header port.h               : not found    
Checking for header poll.h               : yes    
Checking for function poll               : yes    
Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found    
Checking for header sys/queue.h          : yes    
Checking for function kqueue             : not found    
Checking for header sys/select.h         : yes    
Checking for function select             : yes    
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : yes    
Checking for function eventfd            : yes    
Checking for SYS_clock_gettime           : yes    
Checking for library rt                  : yes    
Checking for function clock_gettime      : yes    
Checking for function nanosleep          : yes    
Checking for function ceil               : yes    
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : yes    
'configure' finished successfully (2.239s)
```

----End of configure

----Start of make(this compiles fine!!)

[make output omitted for brevity]

`Waf: Leaving directory /usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/build'`

`'build' finished successfully (21.853s)`

-----End of make

-----Start of make test

```
/usr/bin/python "/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/tools/scons/scons.py" -
j 2 -C "/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/build/default/" -Y "/usr/local/
nodejs/node-v0.4.2/deps/v8" visibility=default mode=release arch=ia32
toolchain=gcc library=static

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `library' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
DEST_OS: linux
DEST_CPU: ia32
Parallel Jobs: 2

Product type: program
python tools/test.py --mode=release simple message
[00:00|%   0|+   0|-   0]: release test-pipe-
head                                                  === release test-
pipe-head ===
Path: simple/test-pipe-head
Command: build/default/node /usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/test/simple/
test-pipe-head.js
--- CRASHED ---
```

...
All of the subsequent tests fail in a similar fashion.

-----End of make test

-----Start of make install (I did not execute make test on the first few tries.it was only later that I used it)

```
adil-X:/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2 # make install

Waf: Entering directory `/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/build'
DEST_OS: linux
DEST_CPU: ia32
Parallel Jobs: 2
Product type: program
* installing build/default/config.h as /usr/local/nodejs/include/node/
config.h
* installing build/default/tools/nodejs.pc as /usr/local/nodejs/lib/
pkgconfig/nodejs.pc
* installing build/default/node as /usr/local/nodejs/bin/node
* installing build/default/src/node_config.h as /usr/local/nodejs/
include/node/node_config.h
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2/build'
'install' finished successfully (0.122s)
```

-----End of make install

I updated the `PATH` variable to include the nodejs bin.

Now nodejs crashes with following error on startup

```
adil-X:/usr/local/nodejs/node-v0.4.2 # node example.js

node.js:0
Segmentation fault
```

still, I can see the node.js version

```
adil-X:~ # node -v
v0.4.2
```

OS/Arch info:

```
adil-X:~ # cat /etc/*release
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-
ia32:core-3.2-ia32:core-4.0-ia32"
openSUSE 11.3 (i586)

adil-X:~ # cat /proc/cpuinfo
vendor_id    :GenuineIntel
cpu family    : 6
model          : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6500  @ 2.10GHz
stepping       : 10
cpu MHz       : 1200.000
cache size     : 2048 KB
```

*With no errors on the way when building from source, I am unable to
figure out the problem.
am I missing something obvious? thanks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed in **nodejs-v0.4.5**.no hassle at all. Maybe there was really a bug in **nodejs-v0.4.2** afterall.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few mechanisms I can suggest to try to track down this problem.

First, use `strace(1)` and `ltrace(1)` on `nodejs`:

```
strace -o /tmp/node.strace -fF nodejs script.js
ltrace -o /tmp/node.ltrace -f nodejs script.js
```

Then look through the `/tmp/node.*` files to discover what it was doing moments before it crashed. **Edit**: `strace(1)` reports the *system calls* that the program makes; as programs interact with the outside world via system calls, it's often the fastest mechanism to finding bugs. `ltrace(1)` reports dynamic library calls, which is frequently a lot more information about the internal workings of the program. Both are useful.

Second, run `dmesg > /tmp/dmesg` and look through the `dmesg` output for the segfault information, it'll look like this:

```
[332430.652393] npviewer.bin[13508]: segfault at 418 ip 00000000f6086d16 sp 00000000ffd8b018 error 6 in libflashplayer.so[f5e19000+b5f000]
```

That's an Adobe Flash crash; comparing the addresses against `readelf -s` output on the program, you might be able to guess how *far* into the function the segfault is occurring, which might help when reading the source code. (It's a long shot to guess by address how far you are into a function, but I've found it useful to know if I should look near the start or end of a function.)

Third, you could run the program with `valgrind(1)`:

```
valgrind nodejs script.js
```

Valgrind is an impressive tool that might require a fair amount of learning to really *know*. The little I've used it, I've been impressed, but I can't give as decent a guide as the other simpler tools.

Fourth, you could run `nodejs` under `gdb`:

```
gdb --args nodejs script.js
```

When it dies, run `bt` to get a backtrace. `gdb` is also an impressive program, and you could probably find the exact line that fails using it, but it too takes a fair amount of learning to really *know*. I've been lucky enough that backtraces were usually enough to find the fault.

With luck you'll be pointed to the exact function that failed, and `ltrace(1)` will give you the arguments of that function. This'll hopefully be enough to track down the specific bug.

Comment: +1 for all the good suggestions.now gdb shows `No Stack`. All I get in the dmesg output is `[ 3736.369391] npviewer.bin[5879]: segfault at 0 ip (null) sp bf81d3dc error 14 in npviewer.bin[8048000+2a000]`

Comment: strace shows `6346  <... nanosleep resumed> NULL)     = 0
6346  nanosleep({0, 900000},  <unfinished ...>
6345  write(2, "node.js:0\n", 10)       = 10
6345  --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
6346  +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++` ...Wow I was thinking along the lines of missing dependencies. I'll have a stab at the source anyway. :)

Comment: @Adil Mehmood, heh, that's an Adobe Flash crash in your `dmesg`. Stupid buggy pile... :) I'm surprised about `gdb`'s `No Stack`, I've never seen that one before. How about the `ltrace` output?

Comment: `tail node.ltrace` produces `12350 memchr("\n  startup();\n});\n\341x\037\265\255\001\202\266!#\265\341a"..., '\n', 18) = 0xb680740e
12350 memchr("  startup();\n});\n\341x\037\265\255\001\202\266!#\265\341a\037"..., '\n', 17) = 0xb680741b
12350 memchr("});\n\341x\037\265\255\001\202\266!#\265\341a\037\265\n", '\n', 4) = 0xb680741f
12350 free(0x0855e740)                           = <void>
12350 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) ---` so npviewer.bin is Firefox's adobe flash player plugin..but it works fine in firefox. so what should be the next logical step? disable flash?

Comment: there is more above the output that I posted earlier.`12350 memchr("    this.loaded = true;\n  };\n\n  "..., '\n', 140) = 0xb68073ab
12350 memchr("  };\n\n  NativeModule.prototype.c"..., '\n', 116) = 0xb68073b0
12350 memchr("\n  NativeModule.prototype.cache "..., '\n', 111) = 0xb68073b1
12350 memchr("  NativeModule.prototype.cache ="..., '\n', 110) = 0xb68073df
12350 memchr("    NativeModule._cache[this.id]"..., '\n', 64) = 0xb6807408
`

Comment: @Adil Mehmood, flash is completely unrelated -- it just happens to be buggy software that frequently shows `SEGV` in `dmesg` output. (It was just convenient to use as a demonstration of how the kernel logs crashes, because I already had a crash in my logs -- as did you. Heh.) I haven't been able to reproduce, and trying to find obvious bugs in the source is eluding me. :( I suggest pasting the `strace` and `ltrace` logs to the mail list and hope for the best.